# Expresso Store - field:register_member default to checked

Tags: expresso-store, members, forms, tags

I don't want to force my customers to register as members (by using the register_member parameter on the checkout tag, but I would like to assume they'd like to by defaulting the checkbox created by the {field:register_member} tag to checked.

I can't find any documentation on wether this is possible. I don't want to have to use JS to do this if possible.

Any guidance much appreciated.

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have more than one page to your checkout process, the easiest way to do this is simply to submit a hidden field on the first page of your checkout which checks the register_member field.

For example, simply add this to the first page of your checkout form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="register_member" value="1" />
```

Now, by the time the customer reaches step 2, the box will already be checked, but they are free to uncheck it if they like :)

Keep in mind that checking it by default only makes sense if you have already given the customer the option to log in. Otherwise you are just making life hard for your repeat customers.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks Adrian. The there is a login form on that page so the user can login - at which point we remove the register as a member option.